# Android - How do I use the same fragment for editing and creating a new instance of my model?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been searching for this answer but did not find an answer at all. It might be too specific. It's a todoApp and I am still migrating my activity's logic to fragments.

TodoListActivity.java (This is where TodoActivity's fragment is called)

```
// ...
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Todo todo = new Todo();
                    TodoSingleton.get(TodoListActivity.this).addTodo(todo);
                    Intent i = TodoActivity.newIntent(TodoListActivity.this, todo.getId());
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
// ...
```

TodoFragment.java

```
//...
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_fragment, container, false);

        todoTitleEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.todo_title_ed);

        if(mTodo.getmTitle() != null) {
            todoTitleEditText.setText(mTodo.getmTitle());
        }

        todoDescriptioneEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.todo_description_ed);

        if(mTodo.getmDescription() != null) {
            todoDescriptioneEditText.setText(mTodo.getmDescription());
        }

        return view;
    }
//...
```

**Question**

I feel like these **if** statements are just not the right way to do it. So how would I use the same fragment for creating new model instances and editing?

Let me know if it is not clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: I just talked to a friend and he said that I could pass a flag into my fragment in order to verify if i am creating a new instance or editing an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make at least any difference between fragments from the same class.

add this method to fragment (change according your needs):

```
public class ActivitiesFragment extends Fragment{

    private int mFragmentType;

    public ActivitiesFragment(){
    }

    public static ActivitiesFragment getInstance(int pageNumber){
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("type", pageNumber);
        ActivitiesFragment fragment = new ActivitiesFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.mFragmentType = pageNumber;
        return fragment;
    }

}
```

and now you can get two different fragments:

```
ActivitiesFragment fragmentOne = ActivitiesFragment.getInstance(1);
ActivitiesFragment fragmentTwo = ActivitiesFragment.getInstance(2);
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same fragment for new model instance,you can do like this:

```
public class TodoFragmentFactory {

    private TodoFragment mFragment;

    private TodoFragment(){

    }

   public static TodoFragment getInstance(Todo todo){
      if(mFragment==null){
        mFragment = new TodoFragment();
      }
      mFragment.setTodo(todo);
      return mFragment;
  }

}
```